# Visual Studio Creating Android project Error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am new on Xamarin visual studio and I want to develop an android project but I got this error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
Actually, I see the error JUST for the C# project and JUST for Android! 
I can create the project for IOS and Android under F# project!! but For C# Android I got the error.

I have installed Android SDK and JDK and it shows a green check on the Android setting.

I use visual studio 2012, I tried to reinstall both Xamarin and VIStudio but the error remains.
would you help me, thanks?

EDIT

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin doesn't support older versions of VS anymore. The recommendation is to use Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 currently:

> Xamarin for Visual Studio supports any Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise) and non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements

Comment: but i see xamarin on tools options . and as i said i can create project for IOS , also android F# , ...

Comment: You are using 5 year old software when a new and free version is available. As mentioned prior, Xamarin no longer supports VS 2012 and thus you should not use it. VS 2017 Community is a free option for many developers to use.